# Python Pandas read_csv of Large File causes memory crash

Tags: python, csv, memory, pandas

I'm trying to read a large CSV file using Pandas. Here are the versions of libraries I'm using:

Pandas '0.14.1'

Numpy  '1.8.1'

The CSV file has the following characteristics:

size: 1.9 GB

lines: 206,074

columns: 9

Using Eclipse to run my code and I get the following error:

```
filenameALL = 'C:/[path]/OutputALL.csv'
all    = pd.read_csv(filenameALL, sep='|', index_col=False, skiprows=[0,1,2], header=None, low_memory=False )

"Console already exited with value: -1073741819 while waiting for an answer."
```

Is the issue on my end or is this a Pandas bug?

Comment: With any programming language, the file readers have limitations. Opening and reading a 1.9 GB file is definitely a strain on the computer and it runs out of memory when trying to read it. This isn't you, its python or pandas.

Comment: for sure this will NOT work. windows can't allocate barely more than 2gb, no matter your free memory. use 64-bit at a minimum