# Python: Proper way to read large dataset without crashing memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, crash, large-data

I read a TDMS binary dataset generated by LabView using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796977/reading-tdms-files-in-python-how-to-use-tdmsinfo-command?rq=1). The file is about 500 MB, so it's not so big as commented in another posted questions as [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293731/python-handling-of-memory) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825522/python-pandas-read-csv-of-large-file-causes-memory-crash).

My computer has a quadcore i7 processor and 8GB RAM memory, uses ubuntu 16.04 and run IPython Notebook (Python 2.7).

I noticed, in the monitor system, everytime that I read the file (~500 MB), it is apparently stored in RAM memory. Data has 8 arrays of 3.3e7 points. When I tried to plot (using matplotlib) only one array, the memory consumption increase to about 1 GB more. So, imagine when I tried to plot the 8 arrays in one plot. I have to restart the kernel to clear from the RAM memory. But what if I need to plot every array?

I experimented this before when read multiples astronomical images.

I tried to found the answer for these looking in questions [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293731/python-handling-of-memory) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825522/python-pandas-read-csv-of-large-file-causes-memory-crash) but these answer are not resolved.

So, the question is: How can I manage the memory for large datasets using python?

Code Example:

```
%matplotlib nbagg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from nptdms import TdmsFile

tdms_file = TdmsFile("20180320_190351_060_PXI-5105.tdms")
root_object = tdms_file.object()

# Iterate over all items in the properties dictionary and print them
for name, value in root_object.properties.items():
    print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))

Timestamp: 2018-03-20 19:03:51.060532343
Digitizer: PXI-5105
SamplingRate: 30000000
PreTrigger: 0.05
PostTrigger: 1.05
TriggerSource: 4
TriggerHigh: 0.95
TriggerLow: -0.95
Offset: 447.0
Longitude: -46.7273776
Latitude: -23.4832443
GPS-Status: self survey not completed

tdms_groups = tdms_file.groups()
print tdms_groups
[u'PXI-5105-Ch0',
 u'PXI-5105-Ch1',
 u'PXI-5105-Ch2',
 u'PXI-5105-Ch3',
 u'PXI-5105-Ch4',
 u'PXI-5105-Ch5',
 u'PXI-5105-Ch6']

dms_Variables_0 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch0")
dms_Variables_1 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch1")
dms_Variables_2 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch2")
dms_Variables_3 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch3")
dms_Variables_4 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch4")
dms_Variables_5 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch5")
dms_Variables_6 = tdms_file.group_channels("PXI-5105-Ch6")

MessageData_channel_0 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch0', 'Frame_1')
MessageData_channel_1 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch1', 'Frame_1')
MessageData_channel_2 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch2', 'Frame_1')
MessageData_channel_3 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch3', 'Frame_1')
MessageData_channel_4 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch4', 'Frame_1')
MessageData_channel_5 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch5', 'Frame_1')
MessageData_channel_6 = tdms_file.object('PXI-5105-Ch6', 'Frame_1')


# Here the data arrays
MessageData_data_0 = np.array(MessageData_channel_0.data)
MessageData_data_1 = np.array(MessageData_channel_1.data)
MessageData_data_2 = np.array(MessageData_channel_2.data)
MessageData_data_3 = np.array(MessageData_channel_3.data)
MessageData_data_4 = np.array(MessageData_channel_4.data)
MessageData_data_5 = np.array(MessageData_channel_5.data)
MessageData_data_6 = np.array(MessageData_channel_6.data)


# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(MessageData_data_1)
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample of your code?  This would help to suggest methods to reduce memory footprint.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt Done!

Comment: One approach I've used with data sets that are in the 4gb+ range (of course, on a system with a lot more memory) was to load only a very small amount of stuff into memory at once. For instance, do you need to load each of the `MessageData_data_k` variables at once? Can you instead load one, process it, load the next one into the same variable, process that one, etc? This stuff seems like it could likely be kept in a loop (which would also simplify your code). Maybe something like `for i in range(7): dms_var = tdms_file.group_channels('PXI-5105-Ch%s' % i) ...` and then overwrite each iteration.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt Actually the consumption of memory is when I read the file 'tdms_file = TdmsFile("20180320_190351_060_PXI-5105.tdms")' and not when define the channels with data 'MessageData_data_k'

Comment: Right.  So rather than reading all of those files at once, can you read them one-at-a-time in, for instance, a for loop?  As you read one in, overwrite the previous value so as to release that memory.  It doesn't look like you're doing anything that requires they all be open at once.  You could do the `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` before the for loop and then do `ax.plot(MessageData_data)` each time you run through the loop.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt There is a way to use the SWAP instead of RAM?

Comment: I imagine swap wouldn't be any faster than just reading the file from disk (no performance benefit).  But no, I don't know how you'd tell python to do that.